unable to connect to cassandra from apache spark:com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer
[cassandra running from docker windows]

and I am running spark from wsl2
spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1

[its spark-shell after the command above]

and when I try to do
data.collect().foreach(println)
I get this error

scala> data.collect().foreach(println)
24/11/21 23:57:24 WARN ControlConnection: [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=62a6b9af), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|id: 0x29a613af, L:/127.0.0.1:43036 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer))
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {localhost:9042} :: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=62a6b9af): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|id: 0x29a613af, L:/127.0.0.1:43036 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)]
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:59)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:261)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:294)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:290)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2458)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1049)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1048)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=62a6b9af): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|id: 0x29a613af, L:/127.0.0.1:43036 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)]
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:167)
  ... 73 more
  Suppressed: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|id: 0x29a613af, L:/127.0.0.1:43036 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): unexpected failure (com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer)
com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
  Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Lost connection to remote peer

I checked the version compatabilities refering
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector
compatabilities
my versions
Cassandra: 5.0.2
cqlsh: 6.2.0 (compatible with Cassandra 5.0.2)
Spark: 3.5.3
Scala: 2.12.18
Java: 1.8.0_432 (Java 8)
as for cassandra connectors, I tried 3.5.1 and 3.5.0 but neither worked.
And I also tried the same in windows (running spark on docker aswell) then also the issue persisted.

did you setup the Cassandra host correctly in spark? as you can see spark is looking at localhost:9042 to connect cassandradb , is that really reachable from where you are running spark? if not you have to set up the right ip address ,etc...

I am running cassandra from docker, exposed to 9042. and yes, I am able to connect to the port through telnet localhost 9042   . where the output is "Connected to localhost.". And I tested both wsl and windows

try the your cassandra docker ip address or the local ip address instaed of localhost in spark and try again ...

I believe you have not set up Cassandra connection properly, replace 127.0.0.1 with proper ip address of the cassandra db host :
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 \
                            --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.5.1
                            --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions


172.17.0.2

yet getting error
ControlConnection: [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/172.17.0.2:9042
``` ...

I was exposing port 7000 of cassandra to 0.0.0.0:9042 . I needed to map port 9042 of cassandra to 0.0.0.0:9042 . As cassandra's CQL client connections listens to port 9042.
As in docker
docker stop cassandradb
docker rm cassandradb
docker run -d --name cassandradb -p 9042:9042 cassandra

It fixes the Cassandra connection.
